# How to blur a memory stream image in Maui

Tags: maui

I load images from database as memory stream and display them in my app, but I need to blur them before I display them.
How can I do that in MAUI android less than android 31 and IOS?
I found some solutions Xamarin but they are not valid for Maui

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74585542/how-to-crossplatform-gaussian-blurr-an-image-using-net-maui

Comment: That is for ImageView also it's only for Android 31 and above

Comment: The question contains an iOS implementation